# Hindi string is not resolved properly on PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to add hindi text using mangal font on PDF.

ISSUE: Some characters are not being resolved properly for hindi strings. Mostly of which consists of 'choti e matra', 'r matra' and characters with 'halanth'. Kindly provide a solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
        document.open();
        FontFactory.register("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Mangal Regular\\Mangal Regular.ttf");
        Font f1 =FontFactory.getFont("Mangal", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        String str="रिन्यूअल सूचना";     //sample text

        Phrase p = new Phrase(str,f1);

        document.add(p);
        document.close();
    }
```

**NOTE: The text being generated on PDF when copied and pasted to word, is resolved correctly.**

Attached the screenshot of the PDF generated after executing the above code.

[image: screenshot of PDF]

[image: screenshot of same content copied on Word from same PDF]

Comment: The solution is to use itext7 with the pdfCalligraph extension.

Comment: as @PauloSoares said try using itext7 with pdfCalligraph extension

Answer (score 2):

iText 5 does not fully support rendering of Hindi text. If you want to use iText, you'll have to use iText 7 with the pdfCalligraph add-on.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("hindi.pdf"));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont("FreeSans.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

String str = "रिन्यूअल सूचना";
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(str);
p1.setFont(f);

doc.add(p1);
doc.close();
```

Output without pdfCalligraph:

[image: Without pdfCalligraph, wrong Hindi]

Output with pdfCalligraph:

[image: With pdfCalligraph, correct Hindi]

[This blogpost](https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/displaying-text-different-languages-single-pdf-document) gives some more background information and a way to select fonts automatically instead of setting them explicitly on the content elements:

```
final PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("languages.pdf");
final PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
final Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
final FontSet set = new FontSet();
set.addFont("fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf");
set.addFont("fonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf");
set.addFont("fonts/FreeSans.ttf");
document.setFontProvider(new FontProvider(set));
```

Comment: @rhens, Is  iText7 with `pdfCalligraph` is paid ? I installed one nuget package `itext7.pdfcalligraph` but it is not displaying hindi font in pdf. I have random strings some are in hindi some are in english. How can I differentiate between two and apply ttf file accordingly ?

Comment: Yes, `pdfCalligraph` is commercially licensed. You can get a time limited trial license if you want to try it out. My answer covers your question about applying fonts: `pdfCalligraph` selects the appropriate fonts and writing systems automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For Itext5 and Hindi, I used the workaround of this site (http://hrishikeshbanik.blogspot.com/2013/11/indic-script-like-bengali-hindi-support.html)
: Convert text to image  whith the font Google Font NotoSans

```
 com.itextpdf.text.Image png = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(textToImage(TEXT_HINDI,font));
       png.scalePercent(50f);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(png)
...
```

Method "textToImage"

```
public static byte[] textToImage(String text,  java.awt.Font fnt) throws IOException, FontFormatException {        
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        try{
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setFont(fnt);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int width = fm.stringWidth(text) ;
            int height = fm.getHeight();
            g2d.dispose();

            img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            g2d.setFont(fnt);
            fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
            g2d.dispose();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write( img, "png", baos );
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();

        return imageInByte;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try below code

```
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import sandbox.WrapToTest;

public class HindiExample {

    public static final String DEST = "results/fonts/hindi.pdf";
    public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new HindiExample().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        Font f = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("\u0915\u093e\u0930 \u092a\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0915\u093f\u0902\u0917", f);
        document.add(p1);
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("\\u0915 \u0915 \\u093e \u093e \\0930 \u0930\n"
                + "\\u092a \u092a \\u093e \u093e \\u0930 \u0930 \\u094d \u094d"
                + "\\u0915 \u0915 \\u093f \\u093f \u093f \\u0902 \u0902"
                + "\\u0917 \u0917", f);
        document.add(p2);

        BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font=new Font(unicode,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10, 60, 30 });
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CUSTOMERS"));
        PdfPCell balanceLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\u0915\u093e\u0930\u092a\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0915\u093f\u0902\u0917", font));
        table.addCell(customerLblCell);
        table.addCell(balanceLblCell);
        table.completeRow();
        table.setSpacingBefore(10);
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }
}
```